# Get jar files from Artifactory when building using gradle

Tags: gradle, artifactory

I am using gradle to build a jar file.
Until now i manually copied the dependant jar files. Now i would like to use Artifactory in order store the external jars and download the most updated versions using gradle.

My Artifacotry configurations is:

```
artifactory {
    contextUrl = '<server>:8081/artifactory'
    resolve {
        contextUrl = '<server>:8081/artifactory'
        repoKey = 'libs-release'
    }
}
```

Now i am not sure how i specify the external jar files to retrieve when compiling. How it should be done?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are using the third-party Artifactory plugin, which isn't mandatory. Anyway, specifying dependencies always works the same, e.g.:

```
dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework:spring-core:3.0.6.RELEASE"
}
```

Much more information about dependency management can be found in the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html).